# How to model associations in DDD approach?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate, aggregateroot

I'm learning DDD approach step by step with imaginary business domain by reading books of Eric Evans and Vaughn Vernon and I try to implement it using in my project using PHP (but it really doesn't matter here).

Recently I've been reading a lot of **Aggregate**, **AggregateRoot** and **Entity** patterns for models that should be defined by a domain. And, frankly, I'm not sure I understand all definitions well so I decided to ask my questions here.

At first I'd like to present my (sub)domain responsible for employees' holidays management which should make answers for my questions easier.

The most trivial case is that the `Employee` can be found in many `Teams`. When the employee decides to take few days off, he has to send a `HolidaysRequest` with metadata like type of holidays (like rest holidays, some days off to take care of his child, etc.), the acceptance status and of course time range when he's not going to appear in his office. Of couse `HolidaysRequest` should be aware of which `Employee` has sent the `HolidaysRequest`. I'd like also to find all `HolidaysRequest` that are sent by `Employee`.

I'm quite sure that things like `DateRange` or `HolidayType` are pure ValueObjects. It's quite clear for me. The problems start when I have to define boundries of entities. I may have bad practices of defining associations by nesting objects in entities, so, please, tell me finding out the definitions of responsibilities here.

1. What is an entity here? What should be an Aggregate and where's the place for AggregateRoot?
2. How to define associations between entities? E.g. an `Employee` can belong to multiple `Team`s or `HolidaysRequest` is authored by `Employee`  and assigned to another `Employee` who can accept it. Should they be implemented as Aggregates?

Why I'm asking these questions? Because few weeks ago I've posted a question here and one of answers was to think about relations between `Employee` and `Teams`, that they should be in the single Aggreate called `EmployeeInTeam` but I'm not sure I understand it in proper way.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: How is the employee's team relevant to holidays requests? What are the invariants to protect here? For instance, can an employee request an holiday if other employees of the same team requested holidays that overlaps? Etc. You cannot define proper AR boundaries without knowing what invariants you are trying to protect.

Comment: @plalx Let's say there's no boundries. Let's say there can be a day where no one is working during the given day. Another scenario: Let's say that at least one of the people in the team MUST BE working while others take sweet vacations. The only thing I need to know is how to model these relations. The case that an Employee cannot take a rest is some kind of event's resposbility isn't it? In th other hand, the employee placing such request has to know he cannot send a holidays request because none of the employees will be available that day. What do you think?

Comment: @plalx To complete my answer, the employee is the author of sent holidays request, so the other `Employee` that is going to have some permission to accept it know who has sent it. So basically the `HolidaysRequest` consist of some HolidaysRequestMetadata and the `Employee`.

Comment: @KubaT I fail to see how you could really have read the 2 books cover to cover (especially Vaughn Vernon's one) and still come up with these questions. Plalx is right, you need to do some domain analysis and transactional analysis of your domain to derive a design. It doesn't appear out of thin air.

Comment: @guillaume31 Sincerly but you've actually failed while reading my question because I didn't write that I've read them "cover to cover". Actually I'm still reading them and writing the code using Vernon's techinques. And probably it's my bad - that I'm starting to use something that I don't understand completely :) Anyway, thanks, I'll read more about it and maybe the answer will appear by itself :)

Comment: It won't appear by itself, you have to work on unraveling your own domain's use cases, commands, events, invariants, consistency boundaries, etc. ;)

Comment: I belive it's going to look like that :)

Comment: The most important part of the blue book is not about aggregates and repositories. It is about context mapping, bounded context and ubiquitous language. As soon as you start modelling at that level, it will become clearer. For me, you have at least two bounded contexts but there is not enough knowledge about the domain. Another hint - you really want to have one entity per aggregate and it would be your root.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing about DDD, is to put focus in the domain, that's why its called Domain *Driven* Design.

When you start asking about relationships, aggregates and entities without even deeply exploring what consists your domain, you're actually looking for database modeling instead of domain.

Please, I'm not saying you're asking wrong questions, nor criticising they, I think you're not wrong at all when trying to put in practice while studying.

I'm not DDD expert, I'm learning just like you, but I'm gonna try to help.

Start by thinking what situation's may arise about **Holydays Management**. When you have different rules for something, you could start by using *strategies* (I'm saying is the final solution).

Building a nice and meaningful domain, is very hard (at least for me). You write code. Test it. Have insights, throw your code way and rewrite it. Refactor it. In your software's lifecycle, you should put focus on domain, therefore you should be always improving it.

Start by coding (like a domain's draft) to see how it looks like. Let's exercise it. First of all, why do we need to manage this stuff? What problem are we trying to solve? Ahh, sometimes employees ask some days off, we want to control it. We may approve or not, depending on the reason they want "holyday", and how is our team status. If we decline and they still go home, we'll late decide whether we fire or discount in salary. Enforcing ubiquitous language, let's express in code this problem:

```
public interface IHolydayStrategy
{
    bool CanTakeDaysOff(HolydayRequest request);
}

public class TakeCareOfChildren : IHolydayStrategy
{
    public bool CanTakeDaysOff(HolydayRequest request)
    {
        return IsTotalDaysRequestedUnderLimit(request.Range.TotalDays());
    }

    public bool IsTotalDaysRequestedUnderLimit(int totalDays)
    {
        return totalDays < 3;
    }
}

public class InjuredEmployee : IHolydayStrategy
{
    public bool CanTakeDaysOff(HolydayRequest request)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class NeedsToRelax : IHolydayStrategy
{
    public bool CanTakeDaysOff(HolydayRequest request)
    {
        return IsCurrentPercentageOfWorkingEmployeesAcceptable(request.TeamRealSize, request.WorkingEmployees)
            || AreProjectsWithinDeadline(request.Projects);
    }

    private bool AreProjectsWithinDeadline(IEnumerable<Project> projects)
    {
        return !projects.Any(p => p.IsDeadlineExceeded());
    }

    private bool IsCurrentPercentageOfWorkingEmployeesAcceptable(int teamRealSize, int workingEmployees)
    {
        return workingEmployees / teamRealSize > 0.7d;
    }
}

public class Project
{
    public bool IsDeadlineExceeded()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public int TotalDays()
    {
        return End.Subtract(Start).Days;
    }

    public bool IsBetween(DateTime date)
    {
        return date > Start && date < End;
    }
}

public enum HolydayTypes
{
    TakeCareOfChildren,
    NeedToRelax,
    BankOfHours,
    Injured,
    NeedToVisitDoctor,
    WannaVisitDisney
}

public class HolydayRequest
{
    public IEnumerable<Project> Projects { get; internal set; }
    public DateRange Range { get; set; }
    public HolydayTypes Reason { get; set; }
    public int TeamRealSize { get; internal set; }
    public int WorkingEmployees { get; internal set; }
}
```

Here is how I quickly wrote this:

- Holydays may be granted or not, depending on the situation and
  reason, let's create a `IHolydayStrategy`.
- Created an empty (*propertyless*) `HolydayRequest` class.
- For each possible reason, let's create a different strategy.
- If the reason is to take care of children, they can take days off if
  the total days request is under a limit.
- If the reason is because the employee has been injured, we have no
  choice other than allowing the request.
- If the reason is because they need to relax, we check if we have an
  acceptable percentage of working employees, or if projects are within
  deadline.
- As soon as I needed some data in the strategy, I used `CTRL + .` to
  automagically create properties in `HolydayRequest`.

See how I don't even know how these stuff are going to be stored/mapped? I just wrote code to solve a problem, and get piece of information needed to resolve it.

Obviously this is not the final domain, is just a draft. I might take away this code and rewrite, if needed, no feelings for it yet.

People may think it's useless to create an `InjuredEmployee` class just to always return true, but the point here is to make use of **ubiquitous language**, to make things as explicit as possible, anyone would read and understand the same thing: "*Well, if we have an injured employee, they are always allowed to take days off, regardless of the team's situation and how many days they need.*". One of the problems this concept in DDD solves is the misunderstanding of terms and rules between developers, product owners, domain experts, and other participants.

After this, I would start writing some tests with mock data. I might refactor code.

This "3":

```
    public bool IsTotalDaysRequestedUnderLimit(int totalDays)
    {
        return totalDays < 3;
    }
```

and this "0.7d":

```
    private bool IsCurrentPercentageOfWorkingEmployeesAcceptable(int teamRealSize, int workingEmployees)
    {
        return workingEmployees / teamRealSize > 0.7d;
    }
```

are specifications, In my point of view, which shouldn't reside in a strategy. We might apply **Specification Pattern** to make things decoupled.

After we get to a reasonably initial solution with passed tests, now let's think how should we store it. We might use the final defined classes (such as Team, Project, Employee) here to be mapped by an ORM.

As soon as you started writing your domain, **relationships will arise** between your entities, that's why I usually don't care at all how the ORM will persist my domain, and what is Aggregate at this point.

See how I didn't create an Employee class yet, even though it sounds very important. That's why we shouldn't start by creating entities and their properties, because it's the exact same thing as creating tables and fields.

Your DDD turns into **Database Driven Design** that way, we don't want this. Of course, eventually we'll make the Employee, but let's take step by step, create only when you need it. Don't try to start modeling everything at once, predicting all entities you're going to need. Put focus on your problem, and how to solve it.

About your questions, what is entity and what is aggregate, I think you're not asking the definition of them, but whether Employee is considered one or other, considering your domain. You'll eventually answer yourself, as soon as your domain start being revealed by your code. You'll know it when you started developing your **Application Laye**r, which should have the responsibility of loading data and delegating to your domain. What data my domain logic expects, from where do I start querying.

I hope I helped someone.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! In meantime and read this and that in the internet about aggregates, especially in context of Event Sourcing. As far as I understand what you did wrote about associations (or lack of them) I started to think about how to think about consistency between events. Assume there's an Employee who requests for a Holiday at 31st December (and today is 21st June). This is the long-living event. What is going to happen when Employee's team name changes or the Employee changes position? Should I keep references to team identity to retrieve the most current value on demand?

Comment: @KubaT perfectly example. This is the kind of question I like to ask to Domain Experts. How we're going to create associations, aggregates depends on their understanding of this kind of situation. As far as I know, talking about event sourcing, you'd never *delete* things. They would be there, so your brand new employee (which belongs to new team or has changed their positions), might not have that Holyday anymore. I'm learning about this concept as well, it's kinda new to me. Let me know if you came to a conclusion, I'm glad If I could help somehow.

Comment: "Not-deleting" things in ES is obvious but I rather thought about associated entities changes problem. Looking at my example, when HolidaysRequest is placed and it contains Employee data, what to do when Employee changes? I can't search all occurences of events in EventStore where this concrete Employee occured. Even if it's aggregate like HolidaysWithEmployee, I can't update it only because Employee data has changed. Right?

Comment: @KubaT you are right. It's not domain's responsibility to track all events in and update them. When employee changes position, domain should fire an `EmployeeChangedPosition` event (maybe to an EventBus), and there comes `EventHandlers` which subscribed to this event and know what to do. You'd have a `HolydayRequestHandler` which would implement interfaces for handling `EmployeeChangedPosition`, `EmployeeFired` and other events and do whatever it had to do. Maybe a fired employee should dismiss the holydayrequest, maybe a change of position should change analysis for their boss.

Comment: @KubaT now, about updating references in database, it's something strange. I sincerely would try to make the ES database not the same as the domain. What about treating domain's dabatase like it always was, updating the actual data, and using a separate database for EventSourcing? If you start to use an ES database to read data, things may get slower, and I think you actually don't need *historic data* for domain. ES allows you to recreate things in any state, you don't need this in domain at all. User might get old states to do a command with "old" data (which then becomes new again).

Comment: Performance is not a problem :) In EventSourcing is very common to create snapshots after n events and reconstitute models from that point. EventStore is perfect for analysis purposes and allows to track and recreate the whole database only with very small events. And that's my point I want to acheive.

Comment: In terms of associatiating entities I don't know which way to go. I can store only reference to associated entity's id so whenever the child entity changes, the parent one knows about it. In the other hand, for some entities it's important to keep state at the point of time when the parent entity was created. My problem is strictly technical - since managing the event store isn't SQL-ish I can't simply do the "join" between two tables. Then, theoritically, should I load the parent entity from event store, then load the child entity from ES, and so on? What's the correct way to do this? Thanks